# Hide and show textbox when a particular option is selected in ext js

Tags: extjs, show-hide

I have to include a checkbox in my code where when someone select on mail, I can give/show options for "To", "CC" and "BCC". When person doesn't select checkbox I want these textbox to be hidden in ext js.

Answer (score 1):

In that case I'd recommend [two way binding](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/guides/application_architecture/view_model_internals.html).

You use a [viewmodel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-viewModel) to bind the checkbox value and then use that value to bind a hidden state onto your "mail" textfields.

Here is a very broadly made working sencha fiddle [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3k7b)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @KaMun's solution, you can use a FieldSet with `checkboxToggle` set to `true`: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.form.FieldSet.html